# Can I combine these two apps (native and hybrid) into one app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an app fully developped with Android Studio.  I need to create a second app and this one I would like to do it with phonegapp.  These two apps are related one to each other... so ideally I would like to combine them both in the same app... By combining I do not mean they need to work together.  I would like them to be downloadad together (as the same app) and be able to go from one to the other withinn the app... so they can be completely two separate apps, but where the user would think it is only one app.  I hope I am making myself well understood, The hybrid app uses the microphone with the Cordova plugin.  At one time I thorugh about placing it with an iframe, but we would lose the microphone which invokes speech recognition Google native in Android, to convert it to text and pass it to edit text.

So my questions is:

1. Can I combine these two apps (native and hybrid) into one app?
2. Would the microphone with speech recognition to convert to text work well in both cases?

Comment: I doubt that you can do it. Its a sandbox per app but in your case you don't just want to communicate between two apps but run under the same sandbox with different technology. Unless, you want to go through the following: Genereate aar file in Phonegap and use this as a library in your android app - here http://imcodebased.com/android-share-code-multiple-applications/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it was a bit of a pain to set up, but I have it working. I am not using PhoneGap, but I am using Construct along with the Cordova plugin, so it should be a similar setup.

First I took all of the web files generated by Cordova and placed them in the `assets` directory (if you do not have an assets directory you can just create one in the `main` directory). Then I used a `WebView` to display the content:

```
public class CordovaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cordova);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);

        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        }

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(mWebView != null) {
            mWebView.resumeTimers();
            mWebView.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mWebView != null) {
            mWebView.pauseTimers();
            mWebView.onPause();
        }
    }

}
```

The `setJavaScriptEnabled()`, `setDomStorageEnabled()` and `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs()` settings all had to be set to `true` or the content would not load. The last setting, `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture()`, was required to allow audio to play.

It will be a little more work to get the Cordova content to interact with the rest of the app though; you will have to use a [`JavaScriptInterface`](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

1) Nothing is stopping you from having two apps that act as one (aside from the downloading part). They can "speak" to one another using dedicated `Intent`s and share data using `ContentProvider`s. You will have to take care of the case where one app is installed and the other isn't.

2) I don't see any particular issue with the the microphone in this scenario.

However, if I were you, I'd opt for using a single app if that is possible. I am not sure what are the phonegapp limitations for this kind of implementation though.